# for loops, indexing, taking the min value of a list

Tags: python, geometry, arcgis

I have two shapefiles: of lakes and of cities. I need to find the closest city to each lake and add the name of the city into the lake shapefile. I have:

```
for lake in lake_cursor:
    lake_geom = lake.Shape
    city_dist_list = [] #create a city dis list = a list of dist from one lake to each city
    for cityID in range(0, city_length-1):
        #obtaining x and y for both cities and lakes
        cityX = citylist_X_Coor[cityID]
        cityY = citylist_Y_Coor[cityID]
        lakeX = lake_geom.centroid.X
        lakeY = lake_geom.centroid.Y
        #calculate distance
        dist = math.sqrt((cityX-lakeX)**2 + (cityY-lakeY)**2)
        #add the dist to the city dist list
        city_dist_list.append(dist)
    closest = min(city_dist_list)
    closestID = city_dist_list.index(closest)

    lake.City_Name = citylist_City_Name[closestID]
    lake.X_Coor = citylist_X_Coor[closestID]
    lake.Y_Coor = citylist_Y_Coor[closestID]
    print closest
```

but I keep getting an error message starting at `lake.City_Name`. The python shell isn't telling me what is wrong - any ideas? And how to fix it as well? Thanks!

the traceback shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx.py", line 71, in <module>
    lake.City_Name = citylist_City_Name[closestID]
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 35, in __setattr__
    return setattr(self._arc_object, attr, ao)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
```

Comment: what error? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: since you are using external library there, print your closetID and check from shell that it is legal you can access citylist_City_Name with this index

Comment: Does the lake database already have a column called `City_Name`? One note concerning performance: you can avoid taking the square root, as the minimum of the squared distance will be for the same city.

Comment: Where is variable city_length set?

Comment: How are you creating your cursor?  It is a UpdateCursor, isn't it? And is it an arcpy.UpdateCursor, or an arcpy.da.UpdateCursor?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to tell for certain, but it sure looks from the traceback like you are trying to do an update in a SearchCursor. A SearchCursor's rows don't have setters. Make sure you are using an UpdateCursor, and don't forget to do a `lake_cursor.updateRow(lake)` for each lake you update.  Below is a simple example of how to use an UpdateCursor.

```
import arcpy
fc = 'c:/temp/temp.shp'
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
    print row.Mapname
    row.Mapname = 'Some Value'
    rows.updateRow(row)

del row, rows
```

This example uses a regular `arcpy.UpdateCursor`. If you have ArcGIS 10.1, then you can use an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`, which will run lot faster. Read about these UpdateCursors [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000064000000) and [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000).